# How to show EOF in Python? / how to identify lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a code which recognizes a text line by line and reverses each line in the output, I dont know how to enter a text with multiple lines (as "input()" function will take the input after the first "Enter" but I still want to enter more lines?

second I don't know how to count the input line by line? whould "split(/n) be an option?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do share any effort you've already put into solving this problem into your question, so we can help you better. Python documentation is excellent, do take a look at http://docs.python.org/3, you'll see that `input()` raises an `EOFError` when EOF is read, but when used to get interactive information from a user in a terminal, you'd normally look for an empty string instead.

Comment: Please stick to one question per post, otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to receive multiple lines of input *interactively* from a user through a terminal, use the `input()` function in a loop:

```
data = []
while True:
    line = input('Enter a line; leave it blank to stop: ')
    if not line:
        break
    data.append(line)
```

However, if you are reading from a pipe (your script being used to recieve piped data from something else), read from `sys.stdin` instead of using `input()` as you can just use that as a file object:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
```

or read it all into a list in one go:

```
lines = list(sys.stdin)
```

In both cases you get lines as a sequence, and you can simply use `len()` to count the number of lines.

Answer (score -1):

Entering multiple lines: use three quotation marks thusly:
"""hello
this is multiple
lines"""

count lines... len(text.split()) or len(text.split('\n')) etc

Comment: This is *not* about literal string input, but about I/O; reading input from `sys.stdin`.